# Python - Pandas - flatten list of dicts column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I've imported a .csv as dataframe but I have a column composed as list of dicts.
How can I flatten it into multiple columns/new df?

example below:

[image]

Comment: You can see the `pandas` function `json_normalize` https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html

Comment: nope, I still don't get it... just to be clear, the field looks like this:
{'order_rows': 
[{
'id': '618934', 
'product_id': '4644', 
'product_quantity': '1', 
'product_name': 'yyyyyy', 
'product_reference': 'T140031', 
'product_price': '2414', 
'unit_price_tax_incl': '24', 
'unit_price_tax_excl': '2414'}, 
{'id': '618935', 
'product_id': '1835', 
'product_quantity': '1', 
'product_name': 'xxxx', 
'product_reference': 'FOR54', 
'product_price': '2114', 
'unit_price_tax_incl': '2114', 
'unit_price_tax_excl': '2114'},
]}

Comment: I solved it, you can check my answer below, thank you for your support

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved like this:

```
df=pd.read_csv(fName, sep=",", usecols=["associations"]) 
list_rows_dicts=[]
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    row_dict=eval(row["associations"])
    for d in row_dict["order_rows"]:
        list_rows_dicts.append(d)
csv_final_df=pd.DataFrame(list_rows_dicts)
```

Comment: That seems a bit too complicated ;) - see my edit (the first version is what you are doing, just with Pandas methods), the second one is imho the "right" way (whatever that means).

Answer (score 0):

You can extract each row into a series and concat them to a dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd

data = []
for row in range(len(df_ass)):
    data.append(pd.Series(df_ass['associations'][row]['order_rows'][0]))
    
df = pd.concat(data)
```

Comment: I tried something similar to yours but I get this error:
KeyError: 'associations' (should be from range.py)

Comment: I just copied that label from your example... Put there the name of the column that has the data from the example

Comment: it was a mispelling error of mine, here's the updated error: TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_30656/2364970080.py in <module>
      1 data = []
      2 for row in range(len(df_ass)):
----> 3     data.append(pd.Series(df_ass['associations'][row]['order_rows'][0]))
      4 
      5 df_ass = pd.concat(data)

TypeError: string indices must be integers

Comment: I solved it, you can check my answer below, thank you for your support

Answer (score 0):

With a dataframe like

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "associations" :[
        '{"order_rows": [{"id": 1, "p_id": 12}, {"id": 2, "p_id": 12}]}',
        '{"order_rows": [{"id": 3, "p_id": 13}, {"id": 4, "p_id": 14}, {"id": 5, "p_id": 15}]}'
    ]
})
```

you can do

```
df = pd.DataFrame(df.associations.map(eval).str.get("order_rows").explode().to_list())
```

or

```
df = pd.json_normalize(df.associations.map(eval), record_path="order_rows")
```

to get

```
   id  p_id
0   1    12
1   2    12
2   3    13
3   4    14
4   5    15
```

Comment: Thanks, but I still get only Nan values

Comment: @FedericoSala Then you need to provide more information. Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/71762131/edit) a small _usable_ example into your question ([mre](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)), that does produce the problem you've encounterd. Otherwise it's just guessing in the dark.

Comment: @FedericoSala Are the items in `df_ass` really dictionaries or are they strings? If they are strings, see my edit.

Comment: as far as I understood yes, unless I'm getting crazy... Is there a way to show you the original .csv file?

Comment: @FedericoSala If strings, then look at the edit at the end of the answer (do somethinglike `df_ass = df_ass.map(eval)` at the start).

Comment: I solved it, you can check my answer below, thank you for your support